# An automorphism of a tensor product commuting with $\mathrm{Id}\otimes g$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose that an automorphism $f$ of $V\otimes W$ commutes with all automorphisms of the form $\mathrm{Id}_V\otimes g$, where $g \in \mathrm{Aut}(W)$. Then, is it true that there exists $h \in \mathrm{Aut}(V)$ such that $f = h\otimes \mathrm{Id}_W$? If not, what additional condition is sufficient to make it true for instance?

Comment: $\mathrm{Aut}(W)$ means $\mathrm{GL}(W)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.